# can we get Featured products from all store in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, multistore

i am working on multi store website.
i want to show all Featured product from all store in main store. 
can we get Featured products from all store in magento ?

Comment: Posting some extra code of what you've done might help trigger some more responses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have some category or attribute that defines these 'featured products'. In that case we can retrieve the collection under scope 0 (admin scope) using [emulation](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/emulate-store-in-magento/).

```
$appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
$initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation(0);

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
   ->addAttributeToFilter('is_featured', 1) // or whatever you use to define featured products
   ->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail')
   ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
   ->addAttributeToSelect('...');

$appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
```

An important note, checking the stock and some other store level dependent will probably not work as expected. So although this is possible it could have some issues

Comment: Thanks for answer. but when i try this code i got

Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /var/www/gala/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816

Comment: did you try the exact code?

Comment: yes. i tryed the exact code

Comment: skip this one `->addAttributeToSelect('...')`. it was an example to indicate you could load more attributes.